# Shared VPC: how to setup firewall rules to access VMs in host project from service projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I successfully shared a subnetwork between two projects and was able to launch a VM on the shared subnetwork from the service project.

What should I do to be able to access that VM from other VMs of the service project (different subnetwork than the shared one)?

I tried to add a firewall rule to the host project, allowing all traffic from a service account of other project and used the service account from the service project VMs, it didn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be more than one solution to what you are looking for. Not only you need to make sure the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls) allow traffic to the appropriate network, you also need to have a routing mechanism between the networks.

The most straightforward approach is having the VM in the service project [use two network interfaces.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces) One attached to the Shared VPC and the other to the service project's network you want to use.

Comment: i solved it with vpc-peering